# NullPointerException при клике на элемент

Tags: java, android, adapter, null

Есть список имен, по которому нажимаю. После чего должен сохраняться нажатый элемент, который я использую в другом фрагменте.

Список загружается, но при кликах на имена выбивает следующую ошибку:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.vm.sai.adapters.PersonAdapter$OnRecItemClickListener.onRecItemClick(int)' on a null object reference
at com.vm.sai.adapters.PersonAdapter$PersonViewHolder.onClick(PersonAdapter.java:57)
```

Код адаптера:

```
public class PersonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {
    List<String> perscategories;
    OnRecItemClickListener onRecItemClickListener;

    public PersonAdapter(List<String> perscategories, OnRecItemClickListener onRecItemClickListener) {
        this.onRecItemClickListener = onRecItemClickListener;
        this.perscategories = perscategories;
    }

    public interface OnRecItemClickListener {
        void onRecItemClick(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView personName;
        private int position;
        private OnRecItemClickListener onRecItemClickListener;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecItemClickListener onRecItemClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            personName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.persname);
            personName.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bind(String text, int position) {
            this.position = position;
            personName.setText(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onRecItemClickListener.onRecItemClick(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.person_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new PersonViewHolder(v, onRecItemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, final int position) {
        personViewHolder.bind(perscategories.get(position), position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return perscategories.size();
    }
}
```

Фрагмент в котором создаю экземпляр класса:

```
private void initializeAdapter() {
    PersonAdapter personAdapter = new PersonAdapter(personCategories, new PersonAdapter.OnRecItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRecItemClick(int position) {
            saveFavorites(position);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(personAdapter);
}
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код, который присваивает значение `onRecItemClickListener = ...`

Comment: У вас onRecItemClickListener null. По приведённому вами коду более ничего сказать нельзя. Вы просто где-то забыли инициализировать эту переменную. Т.е. дело в вашей невнимательности

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил вопрос, с учётом ответа ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное исключение говорит о том, что Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод на объекте, который проинициализирован значением `null`.

Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `onRecItemClick(...)` на объекте `onRecItemClickListener`, в котором находится `null`.

Решением данной проблемы будет инициализация объекта `onRecItemClickListener` (до его использования).

Comment: проинициализировал интерфейс onRecItemClickListener раньше метода onRecItemClick, но увы ошибка по прежнему такая же

Comment: @Inkognito, Покажите строку, в который Вы создаете экземпляр класса `PersonAdapter`.

Comment: обновил вопрос, взгляните пожалуйста.

Comment: @Inkognito, Инициализировали Вы, да не то что нужно. После клика происходит обращения к полю `onRecItemClickListener` класса `PersonViewHolder`, которое не инициализировано. Вы передаете листенер в конструктор класса `PersonViewHolder`, но в конструкторе Вы нигде его не используете. Сделайте присваивание там. А вообще, мне непонятно, зачем у Вас листенер является как полем адаптера, так и полем вьюхолдера.

Comment: в `PersonViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecItemClickListener onRecItemClickListener) {` сделать присвоение? + если я его удалю оттуда, то в onCreateViewHolder тоже придётся его убрать.

Comment: @Inkognito, Да.

Answer (score 1):

Вы передали слушатель в холдер, но не присвоили его переменной холдера.

Можно по разному решить

1. Таки присвоить значение из аргумента конструктора холдера полю холдера.
2. Убрать слушатель из холдера и из его конструктора, сделать класс холдера НЕстатическим и тогда будет использоваться слушатель из поля адаптера, а не холдера.

Comment: 2-ой вариант не очень понятен на словах(  c 1-м разобрался

Comment: У вас слушатель является как полем класса адаптера так и холдера. Если сделать холдер НЕстатическим, то он будет иметь доступ ко всем полям адаптера как его внутренний класс. В таком случае передавать в него слушатель будет не нужно